# How to retrieve the Promise fullfilled value when debugging?

Tags: typescript, debugging, npm, intellij-idea, promise

I am running this [loopback application](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/soap-calculator-tutorial.html) in IntelliJ. In calculator.controller.ts, I put a breakpoint at the promise. This is the code in the controller file:

```
  @get('/multiply/{intA}/{intB}')
  async multiply(
    @param.path.integer('intA') intA: number,
    @param.path.integer('intB') intB: number,
  ): Promise<MultiplyResponse> {

    const response =  this.calculatorService.multiply(<CalculatorParameters>{
      intA,
      intB,
    });
    return response;
  }
```

When I start the debugger, I go through the breakpoints. First breakpoint:

[image]

Second breakpoint:

[image]

As you can see, the Promise status is `pending`. How can I make the debugger show the value when the Promise status gets to `fullfilled`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what a promise is. The promise does not contain the value, it does contain the plan to retrieve it. That means at your second breakpoint nothing really happened so far.

If you want to have a value, you need to `await` for it.

`const response = await ....`

As you defined you method a `async` you need to have an `await`, otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: I thought the debugger had on option for getting the value after the promise is fulfilled. I can get the value with adding .then() in the code, but that wasn't my question